# logrotate behave unusually, how do I debug?

Tags: logrotate, tomcat

```
/path/to/logs/*.out {
        su server server
        daily
        copytruncate
        missingok
        rotate 7
        compress
        dateext dateformat -%Y-%m-%d
}

/path/to/logs2/*.log{
        su server server
        daily
        copytruncate
        missingok
        rotate 7
        compress
        dateext dateformat -%Y-%m-%d
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
            /home/server/server/bin/shutdown.sh && /home/server/server/bin/startup.sh
        endscript
}
```

When I execute this using in server, it behave unusually.

- sometimes the logs are not stored at all, the file is created, but it's of 0 size.
- sometimes server get stopped and don't get restarted.